Azure AppService limit public access with publicNetworkAccess, but which value to use in Bicep?

According to this official documentation the value of publicNetworkAccess can only be enabled or disabled. It reflects the value of the radiobutton in the portal which is the screenshot above. I am aiming for the middle option but have no clue what value to use in my Bicep.
resource appServiceApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-12-01' = {
  name: 'the name'
  location: location
  kind: 'app'
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    httpsOnly: false
    publicNetworkAccess: '' // <-- this can be either 'Enabled' or 'Disabled' according to docs
// etc.

I have some ipSecurityRestrictions futher down in the Bicep to whitelist ip's and I have ipSecurityRestrictionsDefaultAction: 'Deny' in the Bicep too.

az bicep version = Bicep CLI version 0.29.47 (132ade51bc)



Azure AppService limit public access with publicNetworkAccess, but which value to use in Bicep?

To enable the public network address with only selected networks and ip address option, you need to first set publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled' and then include the ipSecurityRestrictions [] block in the code as shown below to restrict the network access for specific Ip's.
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param sku string = 'F1'
param linuxFxVersion string = 'node|14-lts'
resource appplan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2020-06-01' = {
  name: 'ipplan'
  location: location
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
  sku: {
    name: sku
  }
  kind: 'linux'
}
resource appser 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-12-01' = {
  name: 'ipapprest'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appplan.id
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: linuxFxVersion
      vnetRouteAllEnabled: true
      publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
      ipSecurityRestrictions: [
        {
          ipAddress: '10.0.0.0/32'
          action: 'Allow'
          priority: 300
          name: 'myip'
          description: 'xxx'
        }
        {
          ipAddress: 'Any'
          action: 'Deny'
          name: 'Denyip'
          description: 'xxx'
          priority: 214748364
        }
      ]
      ipSecurityRestrictionsDefaultAction:'Deny'
    }
  }

}

Deployment succeeded:




That is exactly what I have. So the string value can be Enabled and Disabled and when it's enabled AND there are ipSecurityRestrictions present, it will display in the portal as the middle option of that radiobutton. It's a bit strange/misleading as there are 3 options in the radiolist and only 2 in the bicep prop

Out of the 3 options, 1 is for disabled and the other 2 are for enabled purpose only with a little bit change. So that is why there are only 2 with the bicep. @JPHellemons

Is your requirement working with my above approach now? @JPHellemons

They could have used a bool then. true/false and not using the property should be default behaviour. But that is a Microsoft thing. Thank you @Jahnavi, I've marked it as solved.
